# JavaScript for making tabs which does not require <head> edition?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I need JavaScript for tabs which doesn't require `<head>` edition (it won't be posible).

I have three links and three divs, I need such thing that on link push would be showed one div, others hidden, on other link push, showed other div and all other hidden then.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="text-align: left;">
            <ul style="margin: 0 0 0 0;">
                <li style="display:inline; margin-left: 3px; text-align: center; width:90px; background-color:#58794c; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;"><a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 28px; text-decoration: none;" href="#">Postage</a></li>
                <li style="display:inline; margin-left: 3px; text-align: center; width:90px; background-color:#558b40; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;"><a style="color: #efda5d; font-size: 28px; text-decoration: none;" href="#">Return</a></li>
                <li style="display:inline; margin-left: 3px; text-align: center; width:90px; background-color:#66ac4a; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;"><a style="color: #efda5d; font-size: 28px; text-decoration: none;" href="#">Payment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="width:324px; background-color:#58794c; color: #efda5d; border-bottom:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;" title="Shipping information"><p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10; margin-top:0;">Available shipping type/It's price/Additional cost for this product:<br />[[ShippingService1]]/[[ShippingServiceCost1]]/[[ShippingServiceAdditionalCost1]]<br />[[ShippingService2]]/[[ShippingServiceCost2]]/[[ShippingServiceAdditionalCost2]]<br />[[ShippingService3]]/[[ShippingServiceCost3]]/[[ShippingServiceAdditionalCost3]]<br />More information about products delivery you will find by clicking <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot/Delivery.html">here</a>.</p></div>
        <div style="width:324px; background-color:#558b40; color: #efda5d; border-bottom:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;" title="Return information"><p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10; margin-top:0;">Product must be returned within [[ReturnWithin]] to this adress <b>[[ReturnAddress]]</b>. For return shipping pays <b>[[ReturnShipPaid]]</b>.<br /> More information about returning products you will find by clicking <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot/Returns.html">here</a>.</p></div>
        <div style="width:324px; background-color:#66ac4a; color: #efda5d; border-bottom:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;" title="Payment information"><p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10; margin-top:0;">Product price is <b>[[FixedPrice]]</b><br />Additional payment instructions for this product: [[PaymentInstructions]]</p></div>
```

And here is an example of what I want: http://www.isdntek.com/tagbot/tabtop.htm

Probably I need to add div names or IDs and have a simple function of showing or hiding the divs (which would be executed on link click), but I can't find one which doesn't require `<head>` editing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the post system accepts certain HTML tags, thus when you need to display literal tags you have to tag them as code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: "I need JavaScript for tabs which doesn't require `<head>` edition (it wont be posible)." — That's any tab library at all (and even if that wasn't the case, if you can't modify the head, then you need to either fix your CMS or fix the business culture that won't let you modify it)

Comment: eBay doesn't allow edit head in listing templates. Anyway thanks for suggestion

Comment: Hey! What's wrong with you guys? Don't downvote question only because it seems trivial or incorrectly asked! Be a little bit polite! Try to fix question or help. Anyone can downvote, only few can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Quentin said, in comment to your question, virtually any JavaScript library that offers tabs widget (or any other solution to build tabs) does not require doing anything in `<head>` section of the page. Well... actually it does, as you put call to your external JavaScript file there:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs.js"></script>
```

But that's just a form of keeping your code clean. If you don't like head so much, you can put the very same line virtually anywhere within your `<body></body>` section and it should work as well.

So, if probably every JavaScript library offering tabs will work without modifications to `<head>`, then let's use the most (or nearly the most) famous in the world -- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

As you may see in given example (click "*view source*"), all you have to do, to get tabs, is to put to your `<body></body>` something like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1 Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2 Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3 Title</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Tab 1 Text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Tab 2 Text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Tab 3 Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then again, jQuery UI authors shows you, that you should put call to newest version of *jQuery* and *jQuery UI* libs into your `<head></head>` section:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But, as I wrote you, you can also put this anywhere, for example, just before `<div>` used to declare your tabs:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    ...
```

That would be all, folks! :]